# Set global Environment variable on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, macos-mojave

I've searched for an answer and read about different ways to do that in Mac but some of them are not relevant for Mojave or just didn't work for me.

I need to set Environment variable in terminal (bash), run script that creates processes, and I would like those processes to know the value of those environment variables.

How can I do that?

btw - writing export ENV_NAME=ENV_VAL in .bashrc or in .bash_profile didn't work.

Answer (score -4):

Works for me. Have you [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)? For example, *~/.bashrc* is only read by interactive shells, not shell scripts. And *~/.bash_profile* is only read by login shells. Again, shell scripts don't usually use the `-l` flag that would make them login shells. Also, if you put an `export VAR=value` statement in your *~/.bashrc* it won't affect your current interactive shell. You need to start a new shell; e.g., by typing `exec bash`. Once you do that you should find the env var is defined. And it will be inherited by any process, including a shell script, you launch from that interactive session.

Note that if you run your script via crontab, for example, then you'll need a different means of setting the env var. For example, by using the `--init-file` flag or the `BASH_ENV` env var.